# Excel "Edit Inside a Cell" Aligns Content Left Instead of Center

Tags: excel, vba, text, alignment, edit

I have an issue with software I have been creating in Excel. At a random point when creating the software, all of the cells are now left aligning temporarily when being edited inside of the cell, rather than maintaining their alignment. Take a look at the attached GIF. Has anyone seen this before?

Why is it that when a new excel file is created, the desired behavior occurs? (text maintains its alignment while being edited)

[image]

Comment: Can you mention how the cells are formatted? E.g. select the cell and press CTRL+1?